# How to check WCF Service host is alive or not from Windows Phone

Tags: android, mono, windows-phone, xamarin

I've tried using the PING class in windows phone to know the status of the hosted server but it says that system.net namespace cannot be used in windows phone.

My Android Equivalent code:

System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping _pingobj = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping(); System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply _pingreply = _pingobj.Send(edittextIP.Text);

this code works fine for android but not windows.

Please suggest me the one, which fulfills my requirement in windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any great way to test this in WP that I'm aware of.  Even the ping test you're using in Android isn't great - a server may not respond to ping requests even when it's available and healthy.

Two approaches you could try:

1. just execute your WCF request, and handle any failure/exception if
   the server is not available
2. execute a simple request to a known server (ie, GET google.com) if
   it succeeds then network is available